# How may I add new relic addon in a java application app deployed in heroku

Tags: java, heroku, jetty, newrelic

How may I add new relic addon in a java application app deployed in heroku.
I already follow all the official tutorials, but it looks like the agent doesn't work.
My application uses an embedded jetty server.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

could you let us know what tutorials you've used?

The guides on newrelic.com for installing the regular Java agent won't work for Heroku. On Heroku there's an add-on for New Relic which should get you going.

Check out this page for the list of New Relic packages available: https://addons.heroku.com/newrelic

For example, you can run `heroku addons:add newrelic:stark` to use the "Stark" New Relic package as listed on that site. You can also add this add-on through the dashboard once logged in.

If this is what you've already tried or if it doesn't work for you, let me know :)